Spring JWT Security
I have a spring boot web application that is composed with multi-microservices. So, is it possible to add the spring JWT security as a microservice? and how to make it the first, either after or before the api-gateway microservice?
Thank you

The easiest approach is to integrate Spring Security (authentication/authorization) directly into the gateway service. I've implemented this setup in multiple projects.
Otherwise, you'd need to forward all requests to your authentication/authorization service (like an interceptor) before sending them to the actual microservice.
